# "His teacher friend Sam helped me a lot." Is it grammatically correct?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Kindly suggest which sentence is most correct.

- His teacher friend Sam helped me a lot.
- His friend Sam, a teacher...
- His friend Sam who is a teacher...

Which is the suitable construction?

Answer (score 1):

Except for the punctuation, all three examples are fine. In the first example, we need to pause when we add the extra information, the name of the friend, so placing a comma before and after "Sam" makes it easier to parse.

1. His teacher friend, Sam, helped me a lot.

For the same reason, another comma is required after "teacher" in the second example.

2. His friend Sam, a teacher, helped...

The last example needs a comma after "teacher".
3. His friend Sam who's a teacher, helped me a lot.

The contraction in "who's" sounds more natural in speech and matches the informality of "a lot." A more formal equivalent would be "a great deal."

Comment: Granted, *placing a comma before and after "Sam" makes it easier to parse*. But in practice native speakers often wouldn't pause in speech at those positions, so it's potentially misleading to suggest including commas in the written form whose only real purpose is to reflect (non-existent) pauses. Not pausing has the effect of forcing "teacher" to be recognised as a "noun adjunct" modifying "friend" (which is itself effectively a noun adjunct modifying "Sam"; few native speakers would pause within ***My [good] friend Sam helped me*** - it's not obvious why adding modifiers should change that).

Comment: ...by which I mean it's possible that by encouraging non-native speakers to parse the text with (relatively unnatural) pauses, you're distracting them from how people *normally* use constructions like *my teacher friend, her mechanic brother*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I don't understand, there is no comma between "His teacher friend" By pausing–not taking deep breaths–it makes it easier for the listener to understand that Sam is a friend who is a teacher, too. Would you not place any commas in:  "His friend Sam a teacher helped me”?

Comment: Because you have to include the article in *His friend Sam **a** teacher helped me*, it's impossible to articulate that without pauses, which therefore *must* be included in the written version. That's not the case with *His **teacher friend Sam** helped me*, where I think the vast majority of native speakers would *not* pause noticeably at any point within the utterance. That's particularly the case because the final words ***helped me*** sound a bit "lost" if preceded by a comma/pause. Which is less the case with *I was helped by his teacher friend, Sam* (where a comma/pause works fine).